# Mysql inserts in the middle instead at the end of table

Tags: mysql

I am new to database. I deleted few rows (till end of table) from a database table. Now every time i execute INSERT query via php, it inserts new row immediately after last deleted row and pushes the previous inserts down by one row.

[image]

As shown in above figure, the rows are deleted from 2019-08-18 (red rectangle) via the query:
`DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date > '2019-08-18'`

Now new inserts have wrong order as shown in green rectangle in above figure. Though the row with date 2019-08-19 is inserted first, it is pushed to the end of table.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `ORDER BY id`? `ORDER BY date`? The `id` is in the right order (43 to 48). In case you need rows in specific order you should define the order.

Comment: Don't rely on the database to order things how you like them. Use ORDER BY clause when pulling, organizing, or viewing data to view it the way you want to.

Comment: But I don't know what causes such behavior? prior to delete query, insert was working as expected; after delete query, WHAT happened???

Comment: Thats how databases work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most relational databases will not return the rows in any particular order *unless you ask explicitly*. They'll just do whatever's easiest. Often that's insertion order, or maybe order on disk, or whatever index was last used. It's really arbitrary and may even change from version to version of the same database platform.

"If you cared you'd ask" is the principle at work here. You didn't ask, so MySQL presumes you don't care.

Add an `ORDER BY` clause to get predictable orders. Otherwise be prepared for the unexpected.

Comment: *"Add an ORDER BY clause to get predictable orders"* A ORDER BY always might not get predictable order..  The ORDER BY order is only predictable when you include atleast one column which has a primary or unique key that would make it fully deterministic ("fixed") .. On non unique values the order is still non deterministic ("random") where values ties..

Comment: @RaymondNijland That's a good point. In this case with unique ID values it would be predictable, but on other values there could be ties which could get shuffled.